# Is it possible to get a cron job to run between certain hours only?

Tags: cron

I'm editing a crontab for a job that I want to run every minute but only between the hours of 10pm and 2am. Outside this time I'd like it to run every 10 minutes, I'm not sure if this is possible though.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: figured this out:  

*/1 22-2 * * *  and
*/10 2-22 * * *

Answer (score 8):

It would probably be best to have it a 2 separate jobs, one for each hourly group

```
* 22-23,0-2 * * * command
*/10 2-22 * * * command
```

Comment: Excellent post!

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to do in two lines.

```
* 22-23,0-2 * * * command
*/10 2-22 * * * command
```

This might be specific syntax for vixie cron, though.  Check `man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Taken from crontab(5):

> Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges
>   are two numbers separated with a
>   hyphen. The specified range is
>   inclusive.  For example, 8-11 for an
>   ``hours'' entry specifies execution at
>   hours 8, 9, 10 and 11.
>
> Lists are allowed.  A list is a set of
>   numbers (or ranges) separated by
>   commas.  Examples: `1,2,5,9'',`
>   0-4,8-12''.

(Assuming Vixie Cron)